# Why are there Lux - EV conversion tables, and not Lux Seconds - EV conversion table?

Tags: exposure, light, light-meter

As far as I'm concerned, Exposure Value is measured in Lux seconds.

However, I see everywhere the conversion formula:

> Lux = 2.5 x 2^EV

So, for instance, EV = 0 means 2.5 Lux.

Where are seconds?

Comment: "As far as I'm concerned, Exposure Value is measured in Lux seconds." You are incorrect. EV is a luminance agnostic way of expressing a combination of aperture value and time value. Period. It matters not if you're in a dark coal mine at midnight or on a white sand beach at high noon on a cloudless day. If you shoot at f/1 for 1 sec, you've used EV-0, regardless of the fact that in the coal mine you'll have a solid black photo and on the beach you'll have a solid white one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photography, unlike mathematics or physics is not an exact science, and thus photographers aren't as exact with units.

If we look at the exposure equation describing camera settings for correct exposure:

```
N^2/t = E*S/C
```

...where N is aperture F-number (e.g. 1.8 for f/1.8 lens), t is exposure time in seconds, E is illuminance in lux, S is ISO speed (unit-less, example: 100 for ISO 100; if you want to describe not camera settings but rather scene brightness then S is strictly speaking on the incorrect side of the equation and you generally assume ISO 100 then) and C is a constant of 250 lux-seconds.

We can immediately observe that both the left and the right side of this equation has units of 1 over seconds, so we can't take a logarithm of that. Yet, photographers do exactly that and take a base-2 logarithm.

Exposure value is defined as:

```
EV = log_2 (N^2/t) = log_2 (E*S/C)
```

...which would be true horror for mathematicians or physicists. To make that less of a horror for these, we could of course say that there's a hidden constant `t_ref = 1 s`, and that the equation is instead:

```
EV = log_2 (N^2*t_ref/t) = log_2 (E*S*t_ref/C)
```

...then you would correctly take logarithm of a unit-less number.

Exposure value, being a logarithm, has no units. If you take a base-10 logarithm of a number and multiply it by 10, you could say the units are decibels (slightly incorrectly as decibel is strictly speaking not a unit). However, base-2 logarithm doesn't have a name as commonly used as decibel.

Comment: The calibration constant C is 250 lux-seconds. Does it mean that the physical correct exposure (achieved through F number, ISO and shutter speed) in terms of lux seconds in the acquired image is around such a vaule?

Comment: It means that at ISO 100, the correct exposure is 2.5 lux-seconds multiplied by lens aperture squared. So at ISO 100 and f/2, you would have 10 lux-seconds as the correct exposure. At ISO 1 and f/1 (you can't find such an ISO 1 camera and you can't find such an f/1 lens), then indeed correct exposure would be 250 lux-seconds.

Comment: I think I hava always seen exposure in a wrong way. Isn't it evaluated at the sensor? If it refers at the lux seconds absorbed by the sensor, its optimal value should be always the same. Or does it refer to the input lux seconds provided by the subject light, measured before it enters the lens?

Answer (score 3):

For that formula to work Exposure Value (EV) has to first be converted to Luminance Value (LV), which is not time based per-se.

LV is the number a vintage handheld spot meter like [the Pentax V](https://retro-pixel.com/the-asahi-pentax-spotmeter-v-ansel-adams-trusted-tool/) gives. On that meter the LV range is 1-19. And once the LV is known it can be divided up any way you like (Ap/SS), and compensated for (ISO). And that is shown by setting the various dials on the outside of the meter to give the appropriate/desired exposure values.

LV is the same as EV at ISO 100 and they are often confused/interchanged; but LV is not the same as EV at ISO 400... The Lux conversion requires you first convert the exposure values to LV, which effectively removes the time basis (i.e. the time result going the other direction is entirely variable).

To put it another way, EV-0 is not *a number*; it is *a set of numbers* to give a "normal" camera exposure, and they include ISO. LV and Lux are not a set of numbers... they are a singular measurement/value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I'm still a bit confused. EV-0 is judged as a normal camera exposure. Let's consider a certain EV-0 number. Since it represents an energy (so lux seconds), how can it be related to just lux, which is a power density? We need to know the time of exposure of such a power density.

Comment: EV is light energy agnostic. At its most basic, it's strictly a combination of aperture and exposure time. Period. No matter how much light is or is not in a scene, if one shoots at f/5.6 @ 1/60, one has used EV<sub>100</sub>11. Ditto for f/4 @ 1/120, or f/8 @ 1/30. They're all EV-11.

Comment: @Kinka-Byo, EV-0 is not a normal exposure any more than any other EV number is. EV-0 is a light density/intensity (LV) that requires a 1sec exposure at f/1 at ISO 100 (or half second at ISO 200, or two seconds at f/1.4). And EV-15 equates to a light density approximately equal to the sunny 16 rule (i.e. strong shadows; f/16, 1/800, 800). And both generate a correct/normal exposure, but only when some combination of correct settings are used.

Answer (score 2):

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value).

The EV is defined as: `EV=log₂(N²/t)` where N is the f-number and t is the exposure time. It is a dimension-less number and there is no notion of luminance here. It's like decibels for sound measurements that technically only measure a ratio between two sounds, it only defines a ratio between two luminances.

If you want to use these numbers as absolute measurements, you have to define a reference. For sound decibels, 0dB is defined as the lowest audible sound for the average ear. For EV, this is defined by an equality in ISO 2720:1974 (the ISO standard that define film/sensor sensitivity): `EV=log₂(L*S/K)` where `L` is the luminance, `S` is the ISO speed, and `K` is the arbitrary calibration constant `K = 12.5`. You will note that the EV depends on the ISO sensitivity, which itself somehow measures how long it takes to capture enough photons, so, yes, there is a time buried in there.